# How to vertically maximize a plot in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard, and I'm trying to find a way to improve the "vertical resolution" of the plots. There is the "Toggle full size mode" button, but when I do that the plot only gets enlarged to full size horizontally. Vertically the plot stays very small, making it hard to see difference in the y-axis (for some reason it adds a blank margin in this mode, which isn't helping either):

[image]

Am I missing a trick to really get "full size" plots?